# NgRoute not loading (modulerr error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through Scotch.io's MEAN Machine book, and I'm nearly done. Problem is I can't get my Angular code to run correctly——even when I'm literally copying the code from their Github. Whenever I open my app on localhost, ngRoute fails to load (or be injected or whatever) correctly.

Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
angular.module('userApp', ['ngAnimate', 'app.routes', 'authService', 'mainCtrl', 'userCtrl', 'userService'])
]);
```

**App.routes**

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
//home page route
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/home.html'
})

//route for the login page
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/login.html',
    controller : 'mainController',
    controllerAs : 'login'
});

//get rid of the hash in the URL (url prettification)

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
var vm = this;

//get user info if logged in
vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

//check to see if user is logged in ON EVERY REQUEST

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

    //get user information on route change

    Auth.getUser()
        .success(function(data) {
            vm.user = data;
        });
});
//this function handles the login form
vm.doLogin = function() {
    vm.processing = true;
    //call the Auth.login() function
    Auth.login(vm.loginData.userName, vm.loginData.password)
        .success(function(data) {
            vm.processing = false;
            //if user is logged in, redirect to user page
            $location.path('/users');
        });
};

//function to handle logging out

vm.doLogout = function() {
    Auth.logout();
    //reset ALL user info
    vm.user = {};
    $location.path('/login');
};
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>User CRM</title>

<!-- FOR ANGULAR ROUTING -->
<base href="/">

<!-- CSS  -->
<!-- load bootstrap from CDN and custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.1/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<!-- JS -->
<!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>

<!-- controllers -->
<script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>

<!-- services -->
<script src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/userService.js"></script>

<!-- main Angular app files -->
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<header>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-if="main.loggedIn">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire text-danger"></span> User CRM</a>
    </div>  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Users</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-if="!main.loggedIn"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn" class="navbar-text">Hello {{ main.user.username }}!</li>
        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a href="#" ng-click="main.doLogout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<main class="container">
<!-- ANGULAR VIEWS -->
<div ng-view></div>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the exact error I'm receiving:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=userApp&p1=Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=userApp
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:21:366
    at a (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:21:7)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:21:250
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:35:424
    at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:35:202)
    at Ob (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:38:435)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:350
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What are you doing to create the error? Do you have html5 mode setup properly on your server?

Comment: Just running it off of nodemon thru the terminal. Updating with exact error now.

Comment: I would try commenting out the html5mode line, if it's not setup properly on your node server it could cause issues. Also what does the angular page say when you click on that error in your browser console?

Comment: Description
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

Using ngRoute
In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

Comment: So that error is saying that your module userApp is having issues with it's dependencies. Make sure that all of those things you are injecting into the module actually exist as another module. You have shown the mainCtrl and app.routes, but do the others exist? If you are copying code, you could be copying the angular.module dependency list but havent gotten to copying the actual modules yet.

Comment: Yep, they all exist!

I was only copying the code when I reached my wits end trying to get this to run correctly. App.routes has ngRoute injected into it, and all of the others exist in the right file directory

Comment: it's probably a typo somewhere. To troubleshoot, I would start by removing all the dependencies you have for userApp and see if it works, then add the dependencies one by one until you find which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'userCtrl' from the dependencies in the userApp module in app.js. You may have created that file, but there probably isn't any content. This should do the trick.

Comment: This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the 'userService' dependency in app.js isn't loaded in the index.html file.

To fix this issue add the userService.js file in your index.html file underneath the authService.js file like so:

```
<!-- services -->
<script src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/userService.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your **index.html** => `<body ng-app="userApp"` so you need add to your **mainCtrl.js** look like this:

```
angular.module('userApp.mainCtrl', [])
```

You also need do the same way to **userCtrl.js, authService.js, userService.js and app.routes.js**.

Now in your **App.js** finally may look like this:

```
angular.module('userApp', ['ngAnimate', 'userApp.Routes', 'userApp.authService', 'userApp.mainCtrl', 'userApp.userCtrl', 'userApp.userService'])
]);
```

> **Edit**

I try your code in plunker but with commenting `<base href="/">` and change

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

for it work in plunker. Here (http://embed.plnkr.co/BHyE6iWDN5uXqiitaMDU/preview) you can visit it with same error in console log. It's seem due to fail load some depedencies which i left empty at some file.

Here (http://embed.plnkr.co/eD4TYgMNq4MDHQZ7p3n0/preview) another plunker that you can see the error has gone, all of depedencies success loaded. Make sure you have correct typo & not missing the depedencies.

Comment: this is not necessary

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it's just a naming convention that some people use. It has no actual effect on the way your app handles module dependencies.